# How can I color all events that match a certain criteria?

Tags: google-calendar

I have calendar entries for all SSL certificates we manage, so that I get a reminder when I need to renew them.

I would like to set all those calendar entries to a specific color, but I can't find an option that would make this easy.

The only way I found was to search for "SSL EXPIRE" (which is the prefix for all these entries) and go through them one-by-one.

Another approach could be to move them all to their own calendar and give that calendar the color I want, but I would prefer a way that lets me keep the entries in whatever calendar I choose.

Answer (score 1):

Colors in Google Calendar as based on a per calendar basis.  If you create a new calendar and add your ssl events to this calendar, you can make it a seperate color.

Comment: That's what I already suggested in my question and you can assign colors to individual events as well.